# Different behavior for return and yield upon entering "with" statement

Tags: python

When I create a class which supports a `with` scope I get different and unexplained behavior when I use yield and return as last calls in the `__enter__` method, code:

```
class TestWith:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val=val

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Entered!")
        yield
        # return

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print(f"In exit:, type: {exc_type}, val: {exc_val}, tb: {exc_tb}")


with TestWith(4):
    print("printme")
```

Output is:

```
printme
In exit:, type: None, val: None, tb: None
```

i.e. "Entered!" is not printed, changing `__enter__` method to be:

```
    def __enter__(self):
        print("Entered!")
        # yield
        return
```

results in:

```
Entered!
printme
In exit:, type: None, val: None, tb: None
```

Why is there a different behavior for those 2 implementations? also I would imagine that "Entered!" would be printed no matter what since it is called before return/yield

Comment: Well, `yield` and `return` do different things, so why do you think they should both work here?

Comment: @KonradRudolph they are. How does they affect a function call happening before they are actually called?

Comment: Because `return` and `yield` are *not function calls*. They are control flow statements, which means that they control how the *entire function* behaves. In the specific case of `yield`, its use leads to the function having completely different semantics, including a different return value and a different sequence of statements.

Comment: This is unrelated to context managers, which only complicate the example. The question is basically "what is a generator function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `yield` in a function definition makes the function a *generator* and works completely differently.  Here's an example:

```
>>> def func1():
...   print('hi')
...   yield
...
>>> def func2():
...   print('hi')
...   return
...
>>> func1()  # returns a generator...doesn't execute the function!
<generator object func1 at 0x000002555B088510>
>>> func2()
hi
>>> g=func1()  # save the generator
>>> next(g)    # execute it to the next yield
hi
>>> next(g)    # No more yields throws an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

`__enter__` is meant to be a normal function, not a generator, so don't use `yield` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing The 'yield syntax' for making a context manager (addind `with` support to a function without needing to make a class).

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def TestWith(val):
    print("Entered!")
    yield
    print("Exit")


with TestWith(4):
    print("printme")
```

Output:

```
Entered!
printme
Exit
```

Comment: Indeed the usage of context manager led me to this bizarre scenario, but it doesn't really answer the question here. Thank you for the example